# Is Gregorian Calendar Ubiqutous in quant finance?

Tags: discounting, settlement

I'm curious to know if there are any organised exchanges where the Gregorian calendar is *not* used for valuation or as a settlement calendar?

Islamic and Hebrew calendars come to mind, but I wonder what particular exchanges this is used for?

I also assume that if it's used for settlement then it must also be used for valuation i.e. discounting. Is this right?

Comment: My reasoning was also that for Sukuk no interest is allowed, so only 'Western' interest-bearing financial products might be dual-listed and therefore use a Gregorian trading calendar.